# List of Lists from a FreqDist output

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I used FreqDist to count the frequency of each tuple in a list of tuples.  The resulting freqdist looks like this:

```
<FreqDist: (1, 3): 3, (1, 4):2, (1, 2): 1...etc.
```

I want to generate one list of lists so that the output looks like this:

```
[[1,3,3], [1,4,2], [1,2,1]...
```

I did the following and it did not work.

```
list3 = []
for key in combofreqdict:
    temp = list(key)
    temp.extend(value)
    list3.append(temp)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
print combofreqlist #<FreqDist: (1, 1): 2, (1, 3): 2, (1, 4): 2, (1, 5): 2, (2, 1): 1, (2, 5): 1, (3, 2): 1, (3, 3): 1, (4, 2): 1, (4, 5): 1, ...>
list3 = [list(k)+[v] for k,v in combofeqlist.items()]
print list3 #[[1, 1, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 4, 2], [1, 5, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 5, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 3, 1], [4, 2, 1], [4, 5, 1], [5, 2, 1]]
```

This uses the `.items()` of `FreqDist` and then combines them by concatenating the tuple and the last item.

Comment: Worked like a charm and so elegant too!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the FreqDist could be changed do dictonary, or it can behave like one, than you can do the following:

```
import collections


# I used ordered dictionary as example, just to have the same order of items
# as in your question.
list1 = collections.OrderedDict([((1,3),3), ((1, 4),2), ((1, 2), 1)])

list3 = [list(k)+[v] for k,v in list1.items() ]

print(list3)
# [[1, 3, 3], [1, 4, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
```

By the way, don't name list as `list`. You are overwriting build-in `list()` function

Comment: This answer is good too.  Marginally less elegant than the other one otherwise I would have picked this one.  Thanks!